# Symfony2: Ajax form submission with dropdown div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

Let's start from the begining.

I've got tab-panned layout with links. When you click a link there is a drop-down checkbox form injected right into html via

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    var projectId = $("#permission-form").attr("data-project-id");
    var userId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    renderModules(projectId, userId, userId);
});

function renderModules(projectId, userId, divId)
{
    $.get(Routing.generate('module_change_permission', {projectId: projectId, userId: userId}))
    .success(function(msg) {
        $('#modules-'+divId).html(msg);
    });
}
```

module_change_permission routing leads right to controller

```
public function moduleAction(Request $request, $projectId, $userId)
{
    $project = $this->get('api.client.manager')->getProject($projectId);
    if (null === $project) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid projectId");
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $modulesInfo = $this->get('acme.modules.modulesinfo');

    $module = $modulesInfo->getModule($project, $projectId, $userId);
    if (null === $module) {
        $module = $modulesInfo->createModule($projectId, $userId);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ModuleType($em), $module[0]);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('GET') && count($_GET)) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($module[0]);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $this->setFlash('modules_success', 'modules_controller.flash.success');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($this->path, array('id' => $projectId)));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Module:module.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'projectId' => $projectId,
            'userId' => $userId,
        )
    );
}
```

Now I would like to do the same thing - submit form but without redirection (just refresh the the specific div). AFAIK I should use AJAX. But the problem is that I don't know how to do the submit part of work.

I've been trying sth like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu-form').submit(function(e) {

var url = $(this).attr("action");

$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: url, // Or your url generator like Routing.generate('discussion_create')
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        alert("Success!");

    }
});

return false;
});
```

but still don't know how to change the controller part.

Answer (score 0):

You have PUT in the ajax declarotion. So to get the data posted by ajax PUT in the Symfony controller use try to use `$data = $request->getContent();`

And also don't use condition `$this->getRequest()->isMethod('GET')`

Or you may change the PUT method to GET (or even POST) and work with the results as you are doing in moduleAction() controller.